# DNS nameserver gets changed after disconnecting from VPN on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I was using Google DNS 8.8.8.8 in Network Manager applet for some time and everything seemed to work fine. A couple of days ago I switched from Manual settings to Automatic and removed Google DNS for additional DNS Servers. I use VPN on a daily basis to connect to my customer's resources and now everytime I disconnect from the VPN my DNS nameserver is set automatically to 8.8.8.8 and it degrades my internet connection performance. I verify this by doing `nslookup`.

```
nslookup www.o2.pl                               
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.o2.pl
Address: 212.77.100.61
```

When I reboot my PC the nameserver is set to 127.0.1.1 and the internet works fine.

```
nslookup www.o2.pl
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.o2.pl
Address: 212.77.100.61
```

When I connect to the VPN and disconnect, the DNS is set automatically to 8.8.8.8. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your VPN pushes down DNS servers for you to use which is Normal for most VPN systems (DHCP being what it is just over the VPN).  How are you activating your VPN?  Network manager applet?

Comment: I use `openconnect` CLI `sudo openconnect -b -u MY_USER --authgroup=any HOSTNAME --pid-file=/var/run/openconnect.pid`

Comment: I've just run a test, I connected to the VPN and ran nslookup again and the DNS server is not 8.8.8.8, it's something else (can't write it here for obvious reasons). I disconnected again and the DNS is set to 8.8.8.8

Comment: Sounds like the OPenConnect software is doing that, and causing the issues.  You know there's an openconnect plugin for Network Manager right that lets you use it as a client to run your OpenConnect stuff?

Comment: Thanx @ThomasWard. I wasn't aware of that. I took a look at the package on launchpad and I found bug section where the first bug is related to....name resolution not working :D

Comment: I've just gave it a shot and I completely lose internet connection so it confirms the issue I mentioned above so this plugin is a trash.

Comment: just thought i'd mention the plugin exists, there's ways to force DNS servers to work right.  The issue however seems to be related specifically to OpenConnect, and whatever config you get pushed to you which resets your DNS to 8.8.8.8 or such.

Comment: Where does it take that 8.8.8.8 from? I removed it from Network Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause and the solution to the problem.

`openconnect` uses `/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script` script, which OpenConnect calls for all routing and DNS setup.
After a bit of googling I realized that I was running
openconnect in the background and was using wrong signal to disconnect
it. Here are the commands I was using:

Connect:

```
sudo openconnect -b -u MY_USER --authgroup=any HOST --pid-file=/var/run/openconnect.pid
```

Disconnect:

```
sudo kill `cat /var/run/openconnect.pid`
```

According to `man kill`, `kill` command, by default, sends TERM signal and
according to `man openconnect` -SIGTERM makes openconnect exit
immediately without logging off or running vpnc-script. So, here we
go, I was using the wrong signal to disconnect openconnect, which was why openconnect wasn't using the `vpnc-script` to restore the routing and DNS. The solution was simple, what I needed was to use
-SIGINT signal in kill command:

```
sudo kill -SIGINT `cat /var/run/openconnect.pid`
```

NOT

```
sudo kill `cat /var/run/openconnect.pid`
```

This is for version v7.06.
Another solution is to install openconnect version 8 from this PPA
[https://launchpad.net/~dwmw2/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect](https://launchpad.net/%7Edwmw2/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect)
which uses the vpnc-script for both SIGTERM and SIGINT.

```
SIGNALS
       In the data phase of the connection, the following signals are handled:

       SIGINT / SIGTERM
              performs a clean shutdown by logging the session off, disconnecting from the gateway, and running the vpnc-script to restore the network configuration.
```